# Multiple components in HOC Portal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have several components that add through a portal to prevent z-index and display issues; including modal and toast notifications.

There is a case where when submitting a form within a modal, if the form successfully submitted, a Toast notification should also appear and the modal should close.

The problem being that the portal unmounts and the Toast notification does not have time to appear.

I don't know how to solve this problem despite my research.

_document.js (because next.js)

```js
<body>
  <div id="app-portal" />
  <Main />
  <NextScript />
</body>
```

Portal.js

```js
import {
    createPortal
} from "react-dom";
import useMounted from "@hooks/useMounted";

const Portal = ({
    children
}) => {
    const mounted = useMounted();

    return mounted ? createPortal(children, document.querySelector("#app-portal")) : null;
};

export default Portal;
```

In order to share the minimum code, assume that the modal is already open when this method runs (so the portal contains the full markup of the modal)

```js
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    await addPlan({
            form: data,
            exchangeSelected
        })
        .then(() => {
            // show toast notification when form is submitted
            toast.success('Thanks !');
            // form is submitted ? Close this modal
            onClose();
        })
        .catch((error) => {

        })
}
```

What could I do to close the modal while showing the notification?

Comment: Couldn't you handle the `onSubmit` outside the portal component/children?

Comment: Not possible. The form is in the modal itself :/